# Can I manually create a registration token for my iPhone to use for Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: ios, django, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, django-push-notifications

I am trying to play around with django-push-notifications to hopefully integrate it with our system soon. Part of our team is working on the app itself within Firebase, but as a Python backend developer, I would like to test out sending notifications to my personal iPhone. I have the proper APNS dev certs, and I have my device ID, but I don't know of a way I can manually create a registration token to allow me to send messages. The way that I understand it from reading the Firebase docs, it is created once a user engages with the app, and the Swift code in the app handles creating/retrieving and storing the user's registration token. Is that the only way a token can be generated? Not sure what the best way of trying to integrate django-push-notifications if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no other way to generate the token other than calling `getToken()` on the client app's side.

You would have to need to ask your iOS dev friend to at least make a simple app that generates the token, so you could use it for testing.